# Need help understanding phrases of the form "x if y"

Tags: meaning, phrases, conjunctions

I regularly find myself confused by phrases of the form "x if y". For example, in the [2010-10-22 issue](http://app.tech.pentontech.com/e/es.aspx?s=1481&e=39693&elq=cbe558a735d3418fb221c7876e4fe951) of his newsletter, Paul Thurrott writes:

> Well, if you're Wall Street Journal technology maven and Apple lover Walter Mossberg, you simply write an unfair review that ignores the product's best features and harps on **obvious if little-needed** functional miscues such as the lack of copy and paste.

Here's another example, from a [TV guide article](http://movies.tvguide.com/movie-news/DVD-Tuesday-Pans-7996.aspx):

> Best known in the U.S. for **formulaic, if handsome, genre films** like Mimic (1997) and Blade II (2002), del Toro

The usage of 'if' in these examples confuses me. What is the intended meaning of these sentences? Can I just substitute "if" with "though"?

Comment: Yes you can for those examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah awesome word! It fits under defintion 3 at [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/if?r=75&src=ref&ch=dic) (the World English Dictionary part) and definition 4 at [Merriam](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/if). I like Merriam's better:

> : even though : although perhaps; *an interesting if untenable argument*

I think it can be used both as a way to make a good quality not as strong, or show some saving grace of a good quality. *an interesting if untenable argument* says that although the argument is interesting, it is untenable. On the other hand, from your TV guide article, *formulaic if handsome genre films* says that the films are formulaic, but at least they're handsome.

I just connected this to a Russian word, зато, which I think can only be used to make bad situations better. *тупая зато красивая* = stupid but pretty.

Comment: The thought to look the word up in a dictionary crossed my mind numerous times, but I was convinced that would be as fruitless as all of the searching on the web I had done. I'm an idiot.

Comment: The Russian equivalent for this *if* is *хотя и*, actually. *Зато*, as you say yourself, is more of a *but* (*for it, in return, in exchange*; German *dafür*). It doesn't make bad situations better, it just puts emphasis on the subsequent word rather than the preceding one. That is, it works exactly the other way round than the *if*. "Stupid but pretty" = "pretty, even though stupid" = "pretty if stupid". Similarly, "pretty but stupid" = "stupid if pretty". Same for Russian, *тупая, зато красивая* = *красивая, хотя и тупая*, and *красивая, зато тупая* = *тупая, хотя и красивая*.