# Please explain what 'if generic' means in this case, or paraphrase it

Tags: meaning-in-context

"The store's design familiar **if generic**, like a miniaturized Whole Foods."
I understand every word of the sentence, but still the meaning is not clear.
The sentence is quoted from an American newspaper and it's about the new Amazon store in Seattle.

Comment: Use citations and/or show your research in your question, if you please.

Comment: Either you've mistranscribed the text, or it hasn't been proofread. It seems to me there's a verb such as ***is / seems / looks*** missing before ***familiar***, and a comma missing after it.

Comment: Related: [adjective + if + adjective](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/381170/adjective-if-adjective-usage-with-commas?s=1|51.7039)

Comment: "The store's design is familiar (if one wished to be unkind, one might even say generic), like a miniaturized Whole Foods." I don't think 'familiar' and 'generic' are disjoint enough to use 'familiar if generic'.

Comment: Related: [Need help understanding phrases of the form “x if y”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4321/need-help-understanding-phrases-of-the-form-x-if-y)

Comment: [CNN](http://money.cnn.com/2018/01/26/technology/amazon-go-store/index.html "Inside Amazon Go: the store of the future - Jan. 26, 2018") says “The store’s design ***feels*** familiar if generic, like a miniaturized Whole Foods.”  (emphasis added), so the OP left out the word ‘‘feels’’, or accurately quoted a newspaper that misquoted CNN.  I agree with FumbleFingers that there should be a comma after ‘‘familiar’’, and I agree with Edwin that the sentence doesn’t make much sense even then.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a sentence, it should read: "The store's design ***is*** familiar if generic, like a miniaturized Whole Foods."

Or it could be a sentence fragment: "The store's design, familiar if generic, like a miniaturized Whole Foods..."

Either way, "familiar if generic" means that it's familiar, but also generic. It looks like other stores we're familiar with, but doesn't evoke anything in particular and lacks distinctiveness.

Comment: Use citations in answers, if you please.

Comment: Sorry! It's a typo. "The store's design is familiar if generic, like a miniaturized whole Foods."